# Show XML node in textbox (Visual studio 2010)

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, textbox

I'm having some troubles with XML (VS2010) ... 
The point is : 
I'm working in a program that you can save "notes" like the notepad.

I have 2 textboxes and 1 combobox.
first textbox is the title, the second is the body of the note and the Combobox is the list of the notes that i already have.

The problem is here, i click in the title of the note in the comboBox and i can't show the note in the textboxes.

My xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <TableNote>
      <note>
        <title>wasd</title>
        <body>wasd</body>
      </note>
<note>
        <title>10</title>
        <body>wasd</body>
      </note>
<note>
        <title>Test1</title>
        <body>wasd</body>
      </note>
    </TableNote>
```

I will be glad if you can help me.